# Why does git ignore-check quote some ignored file in its output?

Tags: git

I've found that `git check-ignore` quotes some, but not all ignored files, in its output.  For example, when I have a .gitignore file that ignores all .project files, I get the following:

```
>git check-ignore .settings\.project .project
".settings\\.project"
.project
```

This quoting of select ignored files is **not** described in the [git check-ignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore).  It is causing a problem in a Python script I'm writing.  How do I tell `git check-ignore` not to quote its output?  If there isn't a way, then how do I "undo" the quoting in Python?

I'm using git version 2.27.0.windows.1 on Windows 10, but eventually need my Python script to run on Linux as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most Git commands produce output that is meant to be read by a human.

A human looking at these two file names:

```
file    one
file    one
```

probably thinks these are the same, but in fact, one of them has a literal tab in it and the other has four spaces.  A computer program can tell these apart easily, but a human can't.

For these reasons, Git will *quote* pathnames that contain characters that a human might find confusing.  This is controlled by the `core.quotePath` setting; see [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).  However, as that documentation notes, most of these commands *also* allow the `-z` option to encode pathnames in a way that is easy to read in computer programs.

> I'm using git version 2.27.0.windows.1 on Windows 10, but eventually need my Python script to run on Linux as well.

The `-z` option is your friend here.  Open a pipe to `git check-ignore -z` and read *bytes* (not strings) from the pipe.  File names are now `b'\0'`-terminated.

Note: not separated, but terminated, so watch out when using `output.split(b'\0')` as you will get one extra entity:

```
>>> output=b'foo\0bar\0'
>>> output.split(b'\0')
[b'foo', b'bar', b'']
```